# Центрирование картинки в div

Tags: html, css

Помогите расположить бэкграудную картинку по центру в div.
Код файла index.php:

```
<table width="100%">

<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div id="logo"></div>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Стили:

```
#logo{
    background-image:url(logo.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:300px;}
```

Comment: А лучше всего посмотри все тут: [http://htmlbook.ru/][1].


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По горизонтали и по вертикали по центру:

```
#logo {
background: url('logo.png') center center no-repeat;
height: 300px;
}
```

либо если только по горизонтали по центру а по вертикали сверху нужно то:

```
#logo {
background: url('logo.png') center top no-repeat;
height: 300px;
}
```

для выставления по центру картинки в блоке попробуйте следующую конструкцию:

```
<style>
    .cl_1 {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .cl_2 {
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>

<div class="cl_1">
    <img class="cl_2" src="logo.png" />
</div>
```

если же брать вашу верстку то:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <div id="logo">&nbsp;</div>
    <td>
</tr>
```

только ширину и высоту дива задать нужно

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ от scorN, также можете посмотреть описание свойства CSS `background-position` [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp).

Comment: как можно убрать отступ сверху? пробовал сделать таблицу absolute и задать top: 0; но не помогло

Comment: Не понятно какой "отступ сверху" ?!

Comment: Еще вместо center можно написать 50%.

Comment: С этим разобрался, но вот как таким же образом центрировать картинку? Не ставя её как бэкграунд?